# Create webapp war releases 'the maven way'

Tags: svn, deployment, maven, release

my webapp consists in mainly two artifacts, java-server.jar and js-client.war. Both are aggregated/overlayed and get additional property files for the target environment. Finally, i get the war file.

Some war files are deployed using tomcat:deploy some by a script but that shouldn't matter at this point.

There are several things I don't like with my approach:

- server and client are released with the maven-release-plugin, the final webapp is not.
- Just by having the final war file I cannot determine for which server it was built.
- I usually need several client/server combinations at once: While I build the beta server with the stable versions, the nightly build server shall operate on the latest snapshots.

How do you maintain, release and deploy (to maven repo) stable/beta webapps? How do you maintain target-server specific configuration settings? How do you keep different versions? Do you have a lot of branches?

Thanks, Jan

Comment: Do both projects have a common parent POM project?

Answer (score 2):

What I'm doing is using Jenkin's extra maven build steps to execute

```
tomcat:deploy
```

after every build. With the right maven profile, that points the builds to our dev server. Then when we want to push to staging, we use the maven release plugin (with Jenkins again) to create a release with a version number that isn't a snapshot. Say we then release 2.0beta3 to staging. This is done with something like:

```
tomcat:deploy -P staging-deploy
```

The profile then ensures we push to the staging server instead of the dev server with a pom entry like this:

```
    <profile>
        <id>deploy-staging</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <server>tomcat-staging</server>
                        <url>http://tomcat-staging.internal:${tomcat-staging.port}/manager/text</url>
                        <path>${tomcat.path}</path>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Finally, getting from staging to live is done completely outside maven and jenkins. I just don't trust maven to not break :-)

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend using a build server like [hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/). It has maven and rcs support. 
You can specify for instance what branch of your source code to build and what maven targets to execute.

We also use hudson to deploy builds to our web servers.

Comment: My question was not how to start the build but how to configure maven and subversion for building for different target platforms.

Answer (score 0):

My situation isn't as complex as yours, so I can only answer this question:

> How do you maintain target-server specific configuration settings?

I try to externalize all configuration so that I'm deploying the exact same WAR file to stage/prod.  I use Spring's context:property-placeholder tag for this.  There are "default" properties files in the WAR, which are overridden by properties in /etc/app/*.properties (c:/etc/app/*.properties on Windows).

As for actual deployment, I currently upload the WAR file by hand, but plan to automate this in the near future.

Comment: Also a possible solution. But configfiles in svn versus configfiles on target system... I have no clue what is better.

Comment: I put sensible defaults in the WAR and allow them to be overridden on the target system.  This also allows me to change properties and restart the application server without having to build/deploy the application.  I've found this to be a huge benefit in my experience, but I'm sure someone could argue the other side.